# WordPress, создание кастомизации контента

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Я не совсем понимаю как мне сделать редактируемый контент на сайте. Есть верстка, в этой верстке есть уже готовые секции с анимацией.

В чем проблема:
Есть секции, которые содержат в себе аналог переключаемых табов, внутрь которых теоретически должно помещаться что угодно (например, пользователь может всунуть туда аккордеон или уникальный список/кнопку/картинку/карусель и прочее, что есть в макете).

Что я уже сделал:

- До этого я использовал Kirki, но тут он никак не подойдет, так как в 2 из 7 секций нужна гибкость, которую он предоставить не может, даже с поддержкой редактора в репитерах.
- Попробовал воспользоваться Elementor-ом, была идея вырезать из него все его "встроенные" виджеты и добавить только свои (нужные мне). Попутно вырезав все ненужные скрипты и стили. Этот вариант я пока отбросил, потому что он  не просто генерирует секцию, он ее оборачивает в свои контейнеры (что ломает верстку, так как у меня в верстке бутстрап и анимированные с помощью зеленых носков секции).
- Как вариант я уже рассматривал сделать эти секции кастомными типами записей, а нужные мне блоки с помощью ACF добавить кастомные аккордеоны и прочее, однако очень хотелось бы редактировать это все либо через wp-customizer либо через page-builder (для удобства пользователя).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый правильный способ - делать свои [кастомные блоки Gutenberg](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/wordpress-gutenberg-block-api-creating-custom-blocks--cms-31168).

Если сложно кодить, можно воспользоваться [плагином Block Lab](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/block-lab).

Ну, и в крайнем случае, воспользоваться методом, которому ранее прибегали все: кастомные типы записей и ACF.